# Sitecore Helix .Net Core example CSS not showing up in CM

Tags: helix, docker

I am hoping someone has encountered this before. I am working with this helix example -

https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/blob/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore/README.md

and I have a question related to this site when running on CM. The styles show up correctly when the site is published and I view the live local URL of https://www.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost.

But when I try previewing on CM or using the `experience editor` the `CSS` and `JS` are trying to use a URL of http://rendering/css/basic-company.css

I am sure it's just something that I missed in the setup but am having trouble locating the issue. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you using https://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost to access the CM? It looks like maybe the cd site is setup as an application (hosted in rendering directory?). The CSS is referenced using ~/ which maps to the root of the application. If the cm isn't an application, maybe that goes to root i.e. rendering/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to add https://www.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost/ to the `Project.BasicCOmpany.config` file and now the CSS is showing up correctly in `CM`.